# Block unencrypted connection to SQL Server via ODBC

Tags: sql-server, encryption, connection, odbc

I recently enabled the encrypted connection to one of my SQL Server instances. I have software that DSN ODBC must connect to this instance.

The database is on a W10 PC while the client is a W11 PC.

I would like the data that the client sends to the server and the server sent to the client to be encrypted. Following the official Microsoft guide (I leave the link below) I managed to configure the connection but I saw that if I create a new ODBC connection without activating the "use strong encryption for data" flag I can still read and write data to the Database. In my opinion it makes no sense, then anyone could connect to the database, even without having the certificate.

How can I prevent / block connection to the database from a PC that does not have the certificate installed?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-encrypted-connections-to-the-database-engine?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: The `ForceEncryption` checkbox mentioned in the documentation link is what requires encrypted connections to your SQL Server instance. But that doesn't mean clients **must** have your SQL Server instance's public key installed in their Trusted Certificates/Publishers store. Most ODBC/JDBC/SNC client drivers have an option equivalent to `TrustServerCertificate=True/Yes;` that means they'll blindly accept any old self-signed certificate and still have an encrypted connection.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. So whether or not the client has the certificate doesn’t matter. If the instance is configured as encrypted ODBC/JDBC/SNC they will connect blindly to the instance.
The only way to force the client to use the certificate is to enable the option "Use strong encryption for data" (I’m always talking about ODBC). This way if I don’t have the certificate I can’t continue with the configuration. is everything correct?

Comment: You could be mixing up server-side and client-side configuration. The docs you linked are for configuring certificates and encryption on the SQL Server instance (server-side), but it sounds like you're asking about the Data Source Wizard's [Use strong encryption for data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/windows/dsn-wizard-4?view=sql-server-ver16#use-strong-encryption-for-data) checkbox, which is the equivalent of the `Encrypt=True/Yes;` option in connection string properties (client-side).

Comment: I probably forumulato badly the question. From as explained to me ODBC/JDCB/SNC allow the connection even without certificate.
Is there no way to stop this from happening? 
Is it not possible to enable connection to the instance only to those who have the public key installed in their Trusted Certificates/Publishers store?
Even without perhaps using an ODBC/JDCB/SNC connection. Thank you for your patience and availability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data will be encrypted using the server's certificate regardless of the client ODBC DSN setting "Use strong encryption for data" when you set force encryption on the database server. Below is the excerpt from the [ODBC driver documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/dsn-connection-string-attribute?view=sql-server-ver16#odbc-driver-17-and-older).

```
+-----------------+--------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Encrypt Setting | Trust Server Certificate | Server Force Encryption |                                                       Result                                                        |
+-----------------+--------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| No              | No                       | No                      | Server certificate isn't checked. Data sent between client and server isn't encrypted.                              |
| No              | Yes                      | No                      | Server certificate isn't checked. Data sent between client and server isn't encrypted.                              |
| Yes             | No                       | No                      | Server certificate is checked. Data sent between client and server is encrypted.                                    |
| Yes             | Yes                      | No                      | Server certificate isn't checked. Data sent between client and server is encrypted.                                 |
| No              | No                       | Yes                     | Server certificate is checked. Data sent between client and server is encrypted.                                    |
| No              | Yes                      | Yes                     | Server certificate isn't checked. Data sent between client and server is encrypted.                                 |
| Yes             | No                       | Yes                     | Server certificate is checked. Data sent between client and server is encrypted.                                    |
| Yes             | Yes                      | Yes                     | Server certificate isn't checked. Data sent between client and server is encrypted.                                 |
| Strict          | -                        | -                       | TrustServerCertificate is ignored. Server certificate is checked. Data sent between client and server is encrypted. |
+-----------------+--------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

> In my opinion it makes no sense, then anyone could connect to the
> database, even without having the certificate.

You may be confusing authentication with encryption. The encryption key exchange occurs during the initial database connection and is not related to authentication. Use Windows authentication for additional security since that ultimately uses certificates to verify user identity.

Answer (score 0):

You can block that specific connection with Trigger of Logon. But you need to know what are you doing, if you write some wrong SQL so nobody connect anymore, so you will need to disable the trigger with administrative console SQLCMD on local machine. I sugest first you learn about, how to use that triggers.

Comment: Interesting, but links or examples would be helpful.